# Why is Scala's Symbol not accepted as a column reference?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Trying the examples of Spark SQL, they seem to work well except when expressions are needed:

```
scala> val teenagers = people.where('age >= 10).where('age <= 19).select('name)
<console>:23: error: value >= is not a member of Symbol
       val teenagers = people.where('age >= 10).where('age <= 19).select('name)

scala> val teenagers = people.select('name)
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Symbol
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression
       val teenagers = people.select('name)
```

It seems that I need an import not documented.

If I bulk importing everything

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util._
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._
```

EDIT: ... and

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
```

it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion you are lacking.

```
val sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = ???
import sqlContext._
```

That has however changed in the recent (and supported) versions of Spark.

Answer (score 4):

Spark 2.0's here where [SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) replaced `SQLContext`.

There is an implicit conversion from Scala's `Symbol` type and Spark SQL's `Column` that's not available in scope.

After you've created a `SparkSession` instance do `import` to have the implicits in scope.

```
val spark: SparkSession = ...
import spark.implicits._
```

See the [scaladoc of `implicits` object](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$implicits$).

It is automatically imported in `spark-shell` and the reason why you did not have to do this explicit import.