# How do I create a Scala sequence of expressions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051660/how-do-i-project-parquet-file-in-spark) lead me to the need to create a sequence of Scala expressions. I seem to be unable to do that.

I have a `SchemaRDD` object `z`:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD =
SchemaRDD[0] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:103
== Query Plan ==
== Physical Plan ==
ParquetTableScan [event_type#0,timestamp#1,id#2,domain#3,code#4], (ParquetRelation ...., Some(Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml), org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@e7f91e, []), []
```

and I want to project it on two columns. `select` should be the answer:

```
z.select _
res19: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression] => org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD = <function1>
```

However, I seem to be unable to generate a `Seq[Expression]`, e.g.:

```
z.select(Seq('event_type,'code))
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Symbol]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression
              z.select(Seq('event_type,'code))
                          ^
```

or:

```
z.select('event_type,'code)
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Symbol
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression
              z.select('event_type,'code) 
                       ^
```

I thought that a symbol was an expression...

so, how do I invoke `select`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spark Sql not loading catalyst?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745396/spark-sql-not-loading-catalyst)

Comment: that other question is not even at all similar to this one.

Comment: nevertheless, the same answer applies :-)

Answer (score 0):

from a private e-mail:

It looks like you're missing this import:

```
import sqc._
```

where `sqc` is your `SqlContext` variable (so it's subtly different from `import SqlContext._`).

This loads a bunch of implicit functions which convert the symbols to an Expression.

If you haven't encountered implicit functions in scala yet it's basically a way to define a function for transparently converting one type to another. e.g. if I define a function like this which takes an instance of Bar and returns a Foo:

```
implicit def toFoo(bar : Bar) : Foo = new Foo(bar.toString)
```

Then, anywhere in the code where I have a function which expects a `Foo` I can pass it a `Bar` instead and the compiler will introduce a `toFoo()` call on it in the background (i.e. "implicitly").

It's one of the most quirky features of scala and very much a double-edged sword. It lets you write very powerful and concise DSLs but at the same time introduces a lot of magic that can make code impossible to follow :-/